# Elasticsearch parent - child mapping: Search in both and highlight

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following elasticsearch 1.6.2 index mappings: parent **item** and child **document**. One item can have several documents. Documents are **not** nested because they contain base64 data (mapper-attachments-plugin) and cannot be updated with an item.

```
"mappings" : {
  "document" : {
    "_parent" : {
      "type" : "item"
    }, 
    "_routing" : {
      "required" : true
    },
    "properties" : {
      "extension" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "term_vector" : "with_positions_offsets",     
        "include_in_all" : true
      }, ...
    },
 }
 "item" : { 
    "properties" : {
      "prop1" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "include_in_all" : true
      }, ...
   }
}
```

I like to search in **both** indices but always return **items**. If there is a match in an document, return the corresponding item. If there is a match in an item, return the item. If both is true, return the item.

Is it possible to combine **has_child** and **has_parent** searches?

This search only searches in documents and returns items:

```
{
 "query": {
  "has_child": {
    "type": "document",
    "query": {
      "query_string":{"query":"her*}
  },
     "inner_hits" : {
      "highlight" : {
             "fields" : {
                 "*" : {}              
             }
           }
       }
}
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
GET index/item/174
{
  "_type" : "item",
  "_id" : "174",
  "_source":{"prop1":"Perjeta construction"}
}

GET index/document/116
{
  "_type" : "document",
  "_id" : "116", 
  "_source":{"extension":"pdf","item": {"id":174},"fileName":"construction plan"}
} 

__POSSIBLE SEARCH RESULT searching for "constr*"__

{
"hits": {
  "total": 1,
  "hits": [
     {
        "_type": "item",
        "_id": "174",
        "_source": {
           "prop1": "Perjeta construction"
        },
        "highlight": {
           "prop1": [
              "Perjeta <em>construction<\/em>"
           ]
        },
        "inner_hits": {
           "document": {
              "hits": {
                 "hits": [
                    {
                       "_type": "document",
                       "_id": "116",
                       "_source": {
                          "extension": "pdf",
                          "item": {
                             "id": 174
                          },                              
                          "fileName": "construction plan"
                       },
                       "highlight": {
                          "fileName": [
                             "<em>construction<\/em> plan"
                          ]
                       }
                    }
                 ]
              }
           }
        }
     }
  ]
}
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a few example documents, and the query output you are expecting to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can answer my question "Is it possible to combine has_child and has_parent" with *no*.

You should only use one at a time on one index.